Не удается получить доступ к React приложению на порту 3000 через мобильное устройство (IIS на порту 80 работает)
Дебажу React приложение на мобильном устройстве, но не могу подключиться к нему через локальную сеть. Вот текущая ситуация:
Мой локальный IP (IPv4): 192.168.1.4, netstat показывает следующие соединения:
localhost:3000 соединяется
~8080 не соединяется
~80 открывает IIS

При попытке открыть 192.168.1.4:3000 на мобильном устройстве соединение не устанавливается, хотя 192.168.1.4:80 открывает IIS (порт 80 настроен и работает).
Файрвол настроен так, чтобы порт 8080 был открыт, и netstat показывает, что порт слушается.
Отключение IIS убирает его из цепочки, но не решает проблему с доступом к порту 3000.
Ранее я использовал эти порты для отладки через мобильное устройство, но после перехода на pnpm теперь не могу подключиться к приложению.
Что я пробовал

Проверил настройки файрвола - порт 3000 открыт
Отключил IIS - это убирает его из цепочки, но проблему с доступом к порту 3000 не решает
Проверил netstat - порт 3000 слушается
Пробовал другие порты, но проблема остается

#​ Дополнительная информация
ОС: Windows
Использую pnpm для управления пакетами
Вопрос
Какие могут быть причины того, что я не могу подключиться к React приложению на порту 3000 с мобильного устройства, и какие шаги я могу предпринять для устранения этой проблемы?

А приложение точно слушает порт 3000 на внешнем интерфейсе, а не только на localhost?

@AlexeyTen да, точно
